# hi i have a problem while installing the angular ide on eclipse

Tags: angular, eclipse

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Angular IDE by CodeMix 3.6.0.202007221454 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.angularide.feature.feature.group 3.6.0.202007221454)
  Missing requirement: Core Plugin for Code Integration 3.6.0.202007202201 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core 3.6.0.202007202201) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.apache.commons.httpclient 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Code Angular 3.6.0.202007202201 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.angular 3.6.0.202007202201)
    To: osgi.bundle; com.genuitec.eclipse.code.core 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Angular IDE Plugin 3.1.0.201905301921 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.angularide 3.1.0.201905301921)
    To: osgi.bundle; com.genuitec.eclipse.code.angular 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Angular IDE by CodeMix 3.6.0.202007221454 (com.genuitec.eclipse.code.angularide.feature.feature.group 3.6.0.202007221454)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.genuitec.eclipse.code.angularide [3.1.0.201905301921,3.1.0.201905301921]
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve and what exactly you did which lead to the error. Please elaborate.